# custom order email magento after placing order

Tags: magento, attributes

Hi i have a custom attribute called "customer_address" in the seller account page.

After the customer places an order, this custom attribute has to be displayed in the email, apart from the default SKU, price, Qty .

Please help with code and file locations

Answer (score 0):

Following link can help you. In this source, you can see that how custom attribute is used in email.

[Add custom attribute in order email templates - Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393479/add-custom-attribute-in-order-email-templates-magento)

For example
you need to override this model : file [magento]\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php

change this function: public function sendNewOrderEmail()

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
 'order' => $this, 'billing' => $this->getBillingAddress(),
 'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml,
 'custom' => $customvariable //your custom variable here )
);
```

open this file [magento]\app\locale\en_US\template\email\sales\order_new.html

add your custom variable in email template where you want. you can add like this : {{var custom}} I hope this will be helpful to you.

Comment: <events>
<checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
    <observers>
      <Metro_Purchaseorder>                     
       <class>metro_purchaseorder/observer</class>
       <method>shipmentEmail</method>
      </Metro_Purchaseorder>
    </observers>
   </checkout_type_onepage_save_order_after>
  </events>                                                                               Its not working, which event am i supposed to use to trigger the event at checkout page, i want to fetch the company address attribute value in the order email